# How can I reproduce the attached bar-chart in Tableau?

Tags: charts, bar-chart, tableau-api

[image: My bar-chart - example]

I have weeks as dimensions and all other columns as measures.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is already in tableau, what you need to do is add weeks to the columns shelf. Drag "measure values" to the rows shelf and "measure names" to the colors mark. This will create the desired result. I entered dummy numbers in the same manner that was shown on your image and this was what I came up with. You can disregard the filter on "measure names" as it is added automatically to deal with the null values.

[image]

Comment: That's awesome! I'm glad I could help, do you think you could mark the answer as an accepted one? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Stephen! Sorry, I'm a new user here and I can't find where I can mark your answer, could you, please, advise?:)